# Speed up charging

Tags: current, electromagnetism, charger

Is there a way to create changing magnetic field that goes from positive to zero and then back to positive, regarding a sinusoidal wave.

The purpose of this is to induce a coil of wire to move in only one direction.  Such as, when charging you phone, you want to speed up the current. All you do is put this special coil of wire around it and voila, you have a faster charging cable.

Is this theory right?

Comment: "speed up the current" Uh oh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be a describing a sort of free-form transformer.

It is indeed possible to drive a coil with a signal having a DC bias, such that the field varies between zero and a strength in one polarity without ever passing through zero to the opposite polarity.

However, this will not couple to the secondary of a transformer.  Magnetic coupling relies on the *change* in the field, and change is an *incremental* value - mathematically a derivative.  So the signal *induced* in the secondary has lost the DC offset of that driven through the primary.  But as transformer core saturation (which drives core size selection) is sensitive to the offset, driving transformers with unipolar sources having DC offset is generally avoided, since it requires a larger core for no difference in accomplished result.

It would also be very hard to transfer meaningful power with such a loosely surrounding coil with no core or multi-turn secondary to couple to, unless you used really insane drive levels in your primary.  Look to existing inductive charging setups to get a sense of what would be required on the receiving side for a practical system.

But even *if* you could overdrive the charging in this or some other way, that would be a **truly terrible idea**.  Modern USB-connector phones utilize internal charge controllers which are supposed to be carefully engineered to not exceed what the battery can safely handle, so trying to defeat those protections and charge faster than designed is not something you should do by any means.  If you want the maximum *designed* charging rate of your phone, use it with a good power source of rated voltage, capable of high current, and implementing whatever resistors, USB-C signalling or vendor-unique scheme the phone looks for to know that the power source can source more than a legacy USB level of power.  The charge controller should then decide what of that available power it is *appropriate* to use at any point in the charging process.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a constant DC current to an AC current and make a **unipolar magnetic field** into an inductive coil is what you are asking.

What is the DC response in a transformer?

zero, due to mutual coupling at DC